# Parsing OWL/RDF filed in Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, bigdata, ontology

I would like to know if it is possible to parse OWL or RDF (Big) files in Hadoop?

If yes, please tell me how. 
if no, please tell me the solution.

Thank you in advance

Comment: It's possible, sure,  but you'll need to either find someone who's already defined a custom InputFormat for those files, or write it yourself. In order to do this, you'll need to have a deep knowledge of the entire syntax and structure of your input

Comment: Perhaps [Jena Elephas](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/hadoop/index.html)...